# Getting boolean returns inside a request.get node call

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, return

Forgive me as its been a long while since I've dabbled in Javascript (C# guy) but I'm having some trouble using returns as a boolean conditional. I'm thinking somehow its because they're within the `request.get`, since whenever I put the `return true` outside of the `request.get` they return ins no longer undefined. I've spent a lot of time looking this up and trying different things, even to the point where it was just silly. I appreciate the help in advance.

```
var decisions = {

        sellExchange: function(rate, quantity) {
            if (this.checkDollarBallance(rate, quantity)) {
                //Do Something
            }
        },

        checkDollarBallance: function(rate, quantity) {
            request.get('http:123.123.123.123/exampleNodePage', function (error, response, body) {
                let balanceStatus = JSON.parse(body);
                if (balanceStatus.Available < (+rate * +quantity)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: How is your request varaible defined? Are you trying to render content back to the frontend?

Comment: const request = require('request'); is how its defined. No, this logic remains on the server.

Comment: See if `return request.get("...")` works. That is, add the word `return` before your `request` function. It appears that the values are returned inside of the `request` function only, and so aren't being returned by the wrapping `checkDollarBallance` (typo there btw) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know that `request.get()` is asynchronous function. So you can get the result of it using a callback or promise.

Using a callback

```
var decisions = {

    sellExchange: function(rate, quantity) {
        this.checkDollarBallance(rate, quantity, function(result) {
            // Do Something
        });

    },

    checkDollarBallance: function(rate, quantity, callback) {
        request.get('http:123.123.123.123/exampleNodePage', function (error, response, body) {
            let balanceStatus = JSON.parse(body);
            if (balanceStatus.Available < (+rate * +quantity)) {
                return callback(false);
            } else {
                return callback(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Using a promise

```
var decisions = {

    sellExchange: function(rate, quantity) {
        this.checkDollarBallance(rate, quantity)
            .then(result => {
                // Do Something
            });
    },

    checkDollarBallance: function(rate, quantity) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request.get('http:123.123.123.123/exampleNodePage', function (error, response, body) {
                let balanceStatus = JSON.parse(body);
                if (balanceStatus.Available < (+rate * +quantity)) {
                    return resolve(false);
                } else {
                    return resolve(true);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Using a promise + async/await (if you are a C# user, `async/await` may be more familiar.)

```
var decisions = {

    sellExchange: async function(rate, quantity) {
        if (await this.checkDollarBallance(rate, quantity)) {
            // Do Something
        }
    },

    checkDollarBallance: function(rate, quantity) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request.get('http:123.123.123.123/exampleNodePage', function (error, response, body) {
                let balanceStatus = JSON.parse(body);
                if (balanceStatus.Available < (+rate * +quantity)) {
                    return resolve(false);
                } else {
                    return resolve(true);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```